# PHP adding nested variable to object overwrites

Tags: php, loops, variables, object

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  Basically, this script is looping through $replies from a query and adding values to the object.  However, its overwriting the ->replies with the last one.

```
$store->{$f->id}->replies = $store->{$f->id}->replies ?? (object)[];
$store->{$f->id}->replies->{$reply->id} = $reply;
```

If this was to loop through 3 replies, it should store:

1. `$store->{$f->id}->replies->one = 'reply 1';`
2. `$store->{$f->id}->replies->two = 'reply 2';`
3. `$store->{$f->id}->replies->three = 'reply 3';`

Instead it only stores the third one:

```
$store->{$f->id}->replies->three
```

Here is full code of the loop:

```
while($f = $q->fetch()) {
    $reply = static::chatter_message_format($f);
    $store->{$f->id} = $f;
    //If checking for posts from friends, user_id will be array
    if(is_array($user_id)) {                
        if($reply) {
            $store->{$f->id}->replies = $store->{$f->id}->replies ?? (object)[];
            $store->{$f->id}->replies->{$reply->id} = $reply;
        }
    } 
}
```

If I echo $reply in the loop, I see each reply.  The $store is being written to a cache file but it seems to only save the last reply for each post.

I code in python mostly but have inherited this project in PHP - a lot of it is over my head but I'm learning rapidly :)  I will be rebuilding this using an API-first approach soon but trying to salvage what I can for prototype.

Comment: Can you put more code in? Like the loop

Comment: You should have used `json_decode($jsondata, true);`

Comment: `(object)[]` can be replaced with `new stdclass`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out. Issue in the loop, this fixed it:

```
if(is_array($user_id)) {    
  if(!isset($store->{$f->id})) {
      $store->{$f->id} = $f;    //Was creating a new object here before the isset check.
}

if($reply) {

    $store->{$f->id}->replies = $store->{$f->id}->replies ?? (object)[];
    $store->{$f->id}->replies->{$reply->id} = $reply;
}
```